# bulk load (and add more later) ledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

we are looking at using hyperledger-fabric to help us with a resource mgmt application, that may have financial transactions in the future. the fabric looks like it solves a number of design requirements quite easily.

one thing not talked about in any of the chaincode solutions is the need to populate the ledger with large volumes (100,000's ) of items and their states.

we also know that new resources will be added over time.

I guess a different chaincode could have a transaction to receive a source URL (or DB connection) and pass that thru secured connection to the assetmgmt chaincode to load from the source and add to the ledger (as we want the asset affinity to the specific chaincode). (can't require to do this on init as one of the requirements is no downtime, so cannot intentionally require shutdown of transaction chaincode)

pointers to other ideas or best practices welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I working on that myself now for 1.x, and look forward to other input. Here's what I know.

In 0.6 I loaded 200k. I was using the Node SDK and reading from a csv file generated from a db. I started having memory issues as the read buffer, invoke queue, etc. started filling up. This is primarily due to the async nature and wanting a confirmation. I resolved by loading in 10k at a time.

You could just fire and forget, but I think you want confirmation.

So you have your client side SDK memory to deal with, whether Node, Java, or CLI. Just like using sqlloader or something.

But you also have your peer, orderer, and kafka settings. Block size, timeouts, lots of settings. Sort of standard db tuning type thinking, but not a lot known about it yet for bulk load, I don't think.

I do a lot of checks within the chaincode. Does the user have permissions to create a record of that type, does the record already exist, etc. So your cc may also impact load times. Most of that for me didn't matter at a live user pace, but became expensive during bulk loads.

I have some concerns about the peers becoming too busy to handle queries during any large load times. I haven't tested anything, but if a load takes whatever, 15 minutes, and can't decently handle queries then that's a problem. Some designs utilize separate peers for queries, and they can be in an HAProxy cluster or similar and rolling updated offline.

Now in 1.x I am optimizing the cc first, the servers params next, and then finally the client. I hope to only bulk load initially, and not ongoing.

Anxious to read any other thoughts.

Comment: thanks for the great feedback.. all issues I am worried about in a distributed, transaction based system.  once initial loading is done, I don't think we would have more than a couple hundred new resources per month.  so I could do the load offline, before the initial startup.                                  
I do think there should be a way to do this without all that overhead.

Comment: Agreed. I am confident there is in 1.x. Just haven't worked through it all yet. Mostly converting my cc to use pass-thru CouchDB and custom indices. That'll help bulk load a lot. And I need it efficient for when I get to 1B+ records. I think we should be able to use custom attributes in the ECerts soon. That'll help on the user permission lookups as I am currently storing them in state. I have 10k users now (test) and hope to support 1M+.